# Произвольное выделение ссылки в safari mac

Tags: css, mac, safari

http://111k.ru/2/ при заходе на страницу в сафари на маке выделяется ссылка https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCKxr.png
Также, листая слайдер можно добиться такого эффекта https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvgJ9.png
Есть и другие моменты. В стилях нет ничего крамольного, нигде описание подобного не нашел, даже через инструменты отследить невозможно это состояние. Ну или у меня не получилось. Если кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста